# Autoencoder very weird loss spikes when training

Tags: python, pytorch, autoencoder, loss

**Introduction:**

I am trying to make an autoencoder learn 32 features like position, velocity, etc in 32 time steps => 32x32 ‘image’.
For this I just made a simple linear model that uses in every layer the Tanh function with an encoder and a decoder that are symmetric.

During training, I added my own version of dropout for just the input. (in the future I will use the `nn.Dropout`)

---

**Problem:**

I get large spikes in loss function “sqrt(MSE)” at irregular intervals. (Batch_Size = 6000)

[Loss Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsuuW.png)

What I have tried: (small test, 1000 epochs max)

1. `clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm = 0.5)`.
2. Tried `ReLu` and `ELU`.
3. Activation function `Batch = N / 2` (I wanted to do `N` but the memory of my gpu was not enough).
4. Not adding noise or dropout (the noise/dropout I think helps but does not solve the problem).
5. Remove the square root on the MSE loss.

Can someone explain to me why this happens and how to fix it?

```
def rand_bin_array(p_zeros, shape):
    size = 1
    for e in shape:
        size *= e
    arr = np.ones(size)
    arr[:int(size * p_zeros)] = 0
    np.random.shuffle(arr)
    arr = arr.reshape(shape)
    return arr

class Autoencoder_Liniar(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(1024, 921),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(921, 736),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(736, 515),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(515, 309),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(309, 128),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(128, 64),
        nn.Tanh(),
    )

    self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(64, 128),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(128, 309),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(309, 515),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(515, 736),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(736, 921),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(921, 1024),
        nn.Tanh()
    )
  
  def forward(self, x):
    enc = self.encoder(x)
    dec = self.decoder(enc)
    return dec

torch.manual_seed(0)
model = Autoencoder_Liniar().cuda()

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

random.seed(0)
epochs = 10000
batch_size = 6000
test_b_size = 5000

train_losses = []
test_losses = []
for i in range(epochs):
  avg_loss = 0
  random.shuffle(train_data)
  for b in range(train_nr // batch_size):
    start = b * batch_size
    data = torch.FloatTensor(train_data[start : start + batch_size]).cuda()

    noise_power = max(0.8 - i/epochs, 0.1)
    noise = torch.FloatTensor(rand_bin_array(noise_power, data.shape)).cuda()
    y_pred = model(data * noise)
    loss = torch.sqrt(criterion(y_pred, data))

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    #torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=0.5)
    optimizer.step()

    avg_loss += loss.item()
    if b % 20 == 0:
      print(f'EPOCH: {i} BATCH: {b} LOSS: {loss.item()}')
  
  train_losses.append(avg_loss / (train_nr // batch_size))

  with torch.no_grad():
    avg_loss = 0
    for b in range(test_nr // test_b_size):
        start = b * test_b_size
        data = np.array(test_data[start : start + test_b_size])
        data = torch.FloatTensor(data).cuda()

        y_pred = model(data)
        loss = torch.sqrt(criterion(y_pred, data))
        avg_loss += loss.item()

  test_losses.append(avg_loss / (test_nr // test_b_size))
```

Added code for getting [gradient's norm over epochs graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/empKN.png) (without noise/dropout)

[Gradient clipped at 0.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZd4e.png)

```
    total_norm = 0
    for p in model.parameters():
        param_norm = p.grad.detach().data.norm(2)
        total_norm += param_norm.item() ** 2
    total_norm = total_norm ** 0.5
    avg_grad += total_norm
    
    optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Why do u sqrt your loss? It is possible that because after you sqrt your loss becomes non differentiable at y_pred = y_true causing this wierd spikes.

Comment: Just now I tried without the sqrt and it is the same.

Comment: Can you plot the gradient's norm over epochs? This way you will get an idea of how to properly clip the gradient. Using `max_norm=0.5` doesn't make sense if arbitrarily chosen...

Comment: @Ivan Sorry for the long wait (my pc is very slow). I have added the gradient graph.

Comment: If you take a look at those spikes on the gradient plot: what I'm thinking is you should probably try and clip at a lower value (lower than `0.5` at least).

Comment: @Ivan, I have tried 0.3, it did help a lot but did not solve 100% of the problem, is this the best possible?

Comment: You could even try lower and see. Also, you may look into adaptive gradient clipping if you have multiple loss terms in your training.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was clipping the gradient with the `clip_grad_norm_`, but at a lower value.

The value was decided after making the gradient's norm over epochs graph.

[image: Graph with clip at 0.2]